# I lost my iPhone and need help figuring out my iCloud email

Tags: ios, icloud

My iPhone 6 got stolen at school and I'm trying to figure out a way to track where it is to see if I just lost it or someone took it.

Unfortunately I need to know my iCloud email. I know the password but I forgot the email. I don't have a back up email for it. It was an iCloud email and something fairly NOT simple. I need answers to how I can track it without knowing my email.

Answer (score 1):

I actually called them and this is what they suggested:

- Check if you received an email from Apple on emails that you use.
- You can ask your friends if you ever talked with them on Face Time.

My personal recommendation would be to call them yourself and ask them. I am sure they will be able to find a way.

Also, I found [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201354). Hope it helps!